How to create the same context menu for different Android versions on compose
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/19SAfq13.jpg)
I am writing the application in compose. The first photo shows the context menu of Android 12 and the second 13, 14 Android. Please tell me how to make the context menu displayed on all versions of Android with round corners.
This is my code:
internal class TextActionCallback(
    val onActionModeDestroy: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    var rect: Rect = Rect.Zero,
    var onCopyRequested: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    var onPasteRequested: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    var onCutRequested: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    var onFormatterBoldRequested: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    var onFormatterItalicRequested: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    var onFormatterStrikeRequested: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    var onFormatterUnderlineRequested: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    var onFormatterLinkRequested: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    var onSelectAllRequested: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    var hasSelection: Boolean = false,
    var isEmpty: Boolean = true
) {
    fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        requireNotNull(menu) { "onCreateActionMode requires a non-null menu" }
        requireNotNull(mode) { "onCreateActionMode requires a non-null mode" }

        onCopyRequested?.let {
            addMenuItem(menu, MenuItemOption.Copy)
        }
        onPasteRequested?.let {
            addMenuItem(menu, MenuItemOption.Paste)
        }
        onCutRequested?.let {
            addMenuItem(menu, MenuItemOption.Cut)
        }
        onSelectAllRequested?.let {
            addMenuItem(menu, MenuItemOption.SelectAll)
        }
        onFormatterBoldRequested?.let {
            addMenuItem(menu, MenuItemOption.FormatterBold)
        }
        onFormatterItalicRequested?.let {
            addMenuItem(menu, MenuItemOption.FormatterItalic)
        }
        onFormatterStrikeRequested?.let {
            addMenuItem(menu, MenuItemOption.FormatterStrike)
        }
        onFormatterUnderlineRequested?.let {
            addMenuItem(menu, MenuItemOption.FormatterUnderline)
        }
        onFormatterLinkRequested?.let {
            addMenuItem(menu, MenuItemOption.FormatterLink)
        }
        return true
    }

    fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        when (item!!.itemId) {
            MenuItemOption.Copy.id -> onCopyRequested?.invoke()
            MenuItemOption.Paste.id -> onPasteRequested?.invoke()
            MenuItemOption.Cut.id -> onCutRequested?.invoke()
            MenuItemOption.SelectAll.id -> onSelectAllRequested?.invoke()
            MenuItemOption.FormatterBold.id -> onFormatterBoldRequested?.invoke()
            MenuItemOption.FormatterItalic.id -> onFormatterItalicRequested?.invoke()
            MenuItemOption.FormatterStrike.id -> onFormatterStrikeRequested?.invoke()
            MenuItemOption.FormatterUnderline.id -> onFormatterUnderlineRequested?.invoke()
            MenuItemOption.FormatterLink.id -> onFormatterLinkRequested?.invoke()
            else -> return false
        }
        mode?.finish()
        return true
    }

    fun onDestroyActionMode() {
        onActionModeDestroy?.invoke()
    }

    private fun addMenuItem(menu: Menu, item: MenuItemOption) {
        if (!isEmpty) {
            if (hasSelection) {
                if (item.groupId == FORMATTERS_GROUP_ID) {
                    menu.add(1, item.id, item.order, item.titleResource)
                        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW)
                } else {
                    menu.add(0, item.id, item.order, item.titleResource)
                        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)
                }
            } else if (item.id == MenuItemOption.SelectAll.id) {
                menu.add(0, item.id, item.order, item.titleResource)
                    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)
            }
        }
    }
}

private const val FORMATTERS_GROUP_ID = 1
private const val DEFAULT_GROUP_ID = 0

internal class FloatingTextActionCallback(
    private val callback: TextActionCallback
) : ActionMode.Callback2() {
    override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        return callback.onActionItemClicked(mode, item)
    }

    override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        return callback.onCreateActionMode(mode, menu)
    }

    override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {
        callback.onDestroyActionMode()
    }

    override fun onGetContentRect(
        mode: ActionMode?,
        view: View?,
        outRect: Rect?
    ) {
        val rect = callback.rect
        outRect?.set(
            rect.left.toInt(),
            rect.top.toInt(),
            rect.right.toInt(),
            rect.bottom.toInt()
        )
    }
}

class SelectionTextToolbar(
    private val view: View,
    private val onFormatterBold: (() -> Unit)?,
    private val onFormatterItalic: (() -> Unit)?,
    private val onFormatterStrike: (() -> Unit)?,
    private val onFormatterUnderline: (() -> Unit)?,
    private val onFormatterLink: (() -> Unit)?,

    private val hasSelection: Boolean,
    private val isEmpty: Boolean
) : TextToolbar {
    private var actionMode: ActionMode? = null
    private val textActionModeCallback: TextActionCallback = TextActionCallback(
        onActionModeDestroy = {
            actionMode = null
        }
    )
    override var status: TextToolbarStatus = TextToolbarStatus.Hidden
        private set

    override fun showMenu(
        rect: Rect,
        onCopyRequested: (() -> Unit)?,
        onPasteRequested: (() -> Unit)?,
        onCutRequested: (() -> Unit)?,
        onSelectAllRequested: (() -> Unit)?,
    ) {
        textActionModeCallback.rect = rect
        textActionModeCallback.onCopyRequested = onCopyRequested
        textActionModeCallback.onCutRequested = onCutRequested
        textActionModeCallback.onPasteRequested = onPasteRequested
        textActionModeCallback.onSelectAllRequested = onSelectAllRequested
        textActionModeCallback.onFormatterBoldRequested = onFormatterBold
        textActionModeCallback.onFormatterItalicRequested = onFormatterItalic
        textActionModeCallback.onFormatterStrikeRequested = onFormatterStrike
        textActionModeCallback.onFormatterUnderlineRequested = onFormatterUnderline
        textActionModeCallback.onFormatterLinkRequested = onFormatterLink

        textActionModeCallback.hasSelection = hasSelection
        textActionModeCallback.isEmpty = isEmpty
        if (actionMode == null) {
            status = TextToolbarStatus.Shown
            actionMode =
                TextToolbarHelperMethods.startActionMode(
                    view,
                    FloatingTextActionCallback(textActionModeCallback),
                    ActionMode.TYPE_FLOATING
                )
        } else {
            actionMode?.invalidate()
        }
    }

    override fun hide() {
        destroyToolbar()
    }

    private fun destroyToolbar() {
        status = TextToolbarStatus.Hidden
        actionMode?.finish()
        actionMode = null
    }
}

internal object TextToolbarHelperMethods {
    @DoNotInline
    fun startActionMode(
        view: View,
        actionModeCallback: ActionMode.Callback,
        type: Int
    ): ActionMode? {
        return view.startActionMode(
            actionModeCallback,
            type
    )
}

Row(`your text`
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(start = paddingTextField)
            .clip(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                    IvaMessengerTheme.dimensions.messageTextFieldCorner
                )
            )
            .defaultMinSize(
                minHeight = IvaMessengerTheme.dimensions.heightMessageTextField
            )
            .background(IvaMessengerTheme.colors.backgroundColors.primary)
    ) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(
            value = LocalTextToolbar provides SelectionTextToolbar(
                LocalView.current,
                onFormatterBold = {
                    richTextState.toggleSpanStyle(NodeInlineMark(NodeInlineMarkType.BOLD))
                },
                onFormatterItalic = {
                    richTextState.toggleSpanStyle(NodeInlineMark(NodeInlineMarkType.ITALIC))
    
                },
                onFormatterStrike = {
                    richTextState.toggleSpanStyle(NodeInlineMark(NodeInlineMarkType.STRIKE))
    
                },
                onFormatterUnderline = {
                    richTextState.toggleSpanStyle(NodeInlineMark(NodeInlineMarkType.UNDERLINE))
    
                },
                onFormatterLink = {
                    onFormatterLink(
                        LinkState(
                            title = richTextState.linkTextOrSelection,
                            url = richTextState.selectedLinkUrl.orEmpty(),
                 )
          )
},
    
   hasSelection = !(richTextState.selection.min == richTextState.annotatedString.text.length && richTextState.selection.max == richTextState.annotatedString.text.length),
                isEmpty = richTextState.annotatedString.isEmpty()
            )
        ) {
            BasicRichTextEditor(
                state = richTextState,
                onValueChange = { changedValue ->
                    textFieldValueState = changedValue

I tried to set the background of the view
1.
class SelectionTextToolbar(
   private val view: View,
   ...
   ) : TextToolbar {...
   override fun showMenu(
   rect: Rect,
   onCopyRequested: (() -\> Unit)?,
   onPasteRequested: (() -\> Unit)?,
   onCutRequested: (() -\> Unit)?,
   onSelectAllRequested: (() -\> Unit)?,
   ) {
   val background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.context, R.drawable.ic_rounded_background)
   view.background = background


I also tried to set actionModeStyle to style

<resources>
<style name="CustomActionMode" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ic_rounded_background</item>
</style>
    <style name="ActionModeStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/CustomActionMode</item>
    </style>
</resources>

perhaps these are not the right options. Please tell me how to do it right.`
